# What is this manga about a male high schooler who just ridiculously excels at everything?

Tags: sakamoto-desu-ga

I used to follow a manga with the main character a first year high school student who just ridiculously excels at everything, and I mean everything. From math to frog jump and handling bullies.

The character is tall with tidy short hair in formal style (like Sanji but black, no bangs and tidier). He wears glasses that he tends to fix gracefully or stylishly like how smart people usually are portrayed in manga, always dresses very neatly, and can run very fast and possibly almost fly. He doesn't talk much unless necessary, and he shows his thoughts through direct actions which most of the time are unpredictable.

The last part that I remember is that he was treated to be a servant by a bully gang leader of the upper year, but he was serving the bully too well, that the bully ended up looking up to him.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like you could be talking about [Sakamoto desu ga?](http://myanimelist.net/manga/48649/Sakamoto_desu_ga). Here's the blurb from MAL:

[image: Sakamoto desu ga? first cover image]

> First year high school student Sakamoto isn't just cool, he's the coolest! Almost immediately after starting school, he began attracting everyone's attention. The girls love him, and most of the boys resent him. There's even a boy in the class who works as a model, but who is constantly upstaged by Sakamoto! No matter what tricks the other boys try to play on him, Sakamoto always manages to foil them with ease and grace. Though Sakamoto may seem cool and aloof, he helps others when asked, such as in the case of the boy in his class who was being constantly bullied. No matter what difficulties Sakamoto encounters, he moves through his high school life with confidence and class!

Comment: Kyaaaaa! That's right! I just remembered. Thank you...

Comment: Don't forget you can mark this answer as accepted if it was what you were looking for (it's not a requirement at all, and you can choose not to do it, just a way of indicating to the rest of the community that you think your question has been answered).

Comment: @JNat, Btw, is this anime worth watching? How would you rank it against the other animes?

Comment: @Pacerier This is a manga, and has no anime adaptation. Nevertheless, I like it — go have a look at its reviews on MAL and see for yourself.